# I have a full calendar with event count for each day: when hovering the count, I want to display those events

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I have a full calendar with event count for each day; when hovering the count, I want to display those events.

I am using full calendar API.

This is I have tried so far:

```
$('#calendar_container').fullCalendar({
                            events: '/core/api/events',

                            eventRender: function (event, element, view) { 
                                 var year = event.start.getFullYear(), month = event.start.getMonth() + 1, date = event.start.getDate();
                                   var result = year + '-' + (month < 10 ? '0' + month : month) + '-' + (date < 10 ? '0' + date : date);
                                   $(element).addClass(result);
                                   var ele = $('.fc-day'+ date +''),count=$('.' + result).length;
                                   $(ele).find('.viewMore').remove();
                                   $('.fc-event').hide();
                                   if ( count> 0) {

                                       $(ele).find('.fc-day-number').after('<small class="viewMore" style="color:blue;" onmouseover="showevents(this)">'+ count+'</small>');

                                   }
```

So where can I call this `showevents(this)`?

Comment: Have you written any code that you can share ? If so, where it is breaking ? If not, are you asking how it fits all together ? In Short, I can't see any question here.

Comment: Hi. Have updated with code. Please see the snapshot too http://snag.gy/Ith8I.jpg